# Redundant pattern match with monoids

Tags: haskell

The following function defines a pretty-concatenation of strings., i.e. one that does not accumulate white space:

```
(><) :: String -> String -> String
x >< "" = x
"" >< y = y
x >< y  = x <> " " <> y
```

The following ought to be the generalisation to any `IsString` type. Type `a` needs to be in the `Monoid` class in order to concatenate with `mconcat` (= `<>` from `Semigroup`):

```
(><) :: (Monoid a, IsString a) => a -> a -> a
x >< mempty = x
mempty >< y = y                          -- redundant pattern match!
x >< y  = x <> (fromString " ") <> y     -- redundant pattern match!
```

Now, strangely, GHC warns that the second and third lines are a redundant pattern match.

This is odd. It's not even clear to me how an `a` that is `(Monoid a, IsString a)` but not `Eq a` can be used here.

What does work, however, is this:

```
(<+>) :: (Monoid a, IsString a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a
x <+> "" = x
...
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: (Your `(<+>)` doesn't even need `Monoid`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mempty` is just a variable name here. You may as well have written

```
x >< y = x
x >< y = y
x >< y = ...
```

Haskell does not automatically do equality tests when you introduce a new pattern with the same name as an existing binding - it just shadows the existing binding. If you want equality, you have to ask for it with `==` tests, e.g. in a guard clause.

```
x >< y
    | x == mempty = y
    | y == mempty = x
    | otherwise = x <> " " <> y
```

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is very common when you starts with pattern matching and bonded named function. When you declare functions and its equations, all things declared at the left part of the equals written in lower case are name variables, for example:

```
 f sum x y = x (sum * y)
```

those names are confusing, because you might think that `sum` is a function, and x and y are numbers, but instead `x` is a function and `sum` and `y` are numbers, and `x` could be any function of type `Num a -> a -> a`. You cannot give a concrete kind of function in the left side.

so :

```
(><) :: (Monoid a, IsString a) => a -> a -> a
x >< mempty = x
mempty >< y = y                          -- redundant pattern match!
x >< y  = x <> (fromString " ") <> y     -- redundant pattern match!
```

there, `mempty` is just a name for you variable and not the actual `mempty` function you are trying to call. You cannot pattern match over a functions of an interface. Just over variables and data types-